# Get sum of total and print it to an element

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do i pass a value from function ?
Is there a way to take result from a function. I make a simple program about ordering pizza. There are 3 options for pizza, 3 options for size(small,medium,large), and some toppings options, with different prices.

So what i think is just that i could get the total by pushing all choosen options values to an array and then use "reduce" method to get the total. Or is there another solution for this ?

```
 var subTotal=[];


function pizzaChoice(menuId) {
//  push result to subTotal array
}

function pickSize(size) {
//  push result to subTotal array
}

function pickTopping(topping) {
    //  push result to subTotal array
}

function calc(){
// add up all using reduce method 
}
```

Comment: That code does not show much. Seems more like a template which you are supposed to complete. Please show in the code what you did, and where it goes wrong. *"is there another solution"*: sure, there are many. *"Is there a way to take result from a function"*: sure, just put it in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too broad, but I would define all prices, than the calculation is an easy step:

```js
var prices = {
    'vegetariana': {
        's': 8,
        'm': 10,
        'l': 12
    },
    'cheese': {
        's': 9,
        'm': 11,
        'l': 14
    },
    'margherita': {
        's': 8.3,
        'm': 10.5,
        'l': 13
    },
};
function getPizzaPrice(name, size) {
    return prices[name][size];
};
function displayPrice() {
    var pizzaName = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var pizzaSize = document.getElementById("size").value;
    var pizzaPrice = getPizzaPrice(pizzaName, pizzaSize);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = pizzaPrice;
};
document.getElementById("name").onchange = displayPrice;
document.getElementById("size").onchange = displayPrice;
displayPrice();
```

```html
<select id="name">
    <option value="vegetariana">Vegetariana</option>
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="margherita">Margherita</option>
</select>
<select id="size">
    <option value="s">Small</option>
    <option value="m">Medium</option>
    <option value="l">Large</option>
</select>
<p>Price: <span id="result"></span></p>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/3c6n4fkv/).

Please note, there are many ways to do same.

Answer (score -1):

The very basic way of getting the result of a function is by returning it.

See example below:

```
function [functionName]([parameters]){
    // do things
    return [your result];
}
```

The things in square brackets are placeholder values, replace them with whatever you want.

Comment: Of course, saving the result to another variable works too, but the usual way of getting the result from a function is by returning it.